# How to install exact minor version of NodeJS (Debian)

Tags: node.js, debian

We have a government certification so we need to install exact version of NodeJS (just for them to approve).

One of the preferred OS's in their guidelines is Debian, so we started with Debian 11 and it was ok, but since we started the document, some changes happened in NodeJS:

We were using these commands:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs=18.15.0
```

Document was written for `v18.15.0`, but version available through the commands above is `v18.16.0` and we're worrying that it may affect their decision. I tried with checking versions list via `apt-get` but no luck, only `18.16.0` or `12` (default version available for Debian). Is that even possible to pin the version, if we're using the method above?

Answer (score 0):

You can install nvm and using nvm install specific node versions.
I tried v18.15.0. I am able to install this version with NVM.

https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.15.0/node-v18.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

Relevent Links

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-22-04/